# How to decode base64

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, base64, decode

I have a problem where json is encoded as base64 and I have to read that base64 and decode it and use the values of json.

My Json Structure:

```
{
  "name" : "myname",
  "id" : "1234568",
  "class" : "science"
}
```

My Base64:

```
ewogICJuYW1lIiA6ICJteW5hbWUiLAogICJpZCIgOiAiMTIzNDU2OCIsCiAgImNsYXNzIiA6ICJzY2llbmNlIgp9
```

How can I decode this and get the values of the class?

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that will do this. What programming language are you using? Also, make sure to know if this is base64 url encoded or not.

Comment: I want to know how we decode it in Java

Comment: Maybe an example like this helps: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_base64.htm

Comment: *I'm curious:* In what way did a **web search** for [`java decode base64`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+decode+base64) fail to give you an answer? --- Question down-voted because it "does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 1):

If you still need help, you can try this:

```
import java.util.Base64;

public class Tmp {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("ewogICJuYW1lIiA6ICJteW5hbWUiLAogICJpZCIgOiAiMTIzNDU2OCIsCiAgImNsYXNzIiA6ICJzY2llbmNlIgp9");
        String original = new String(base64decodedBytes);
        System.out.println("Original String: " + original);
    }
}
```